# Thread непонятный запуск

Tags: многопоточность, c++builder, winsock, udp

**Пишу в Borland C++ Builder 6.** Необходимо разобраться с потоками, решил начать с простой задачи, работающий без потоков. Но даже в простом зашел в тупик. *Задача: есть сервер и клиент (камп и ноут, связаны Ethernet кабелем), на сервер, идет передача данных по UDP протоколу с помощью WinSock.* Всё работает даже с потоками но странно. Я так понял что если прописать

```
ThreadUDPServer *thr;
thr = new ThreadUDPServer(false);
```

То едет запуск потока и передача управления в метод **Execute()**. Но этого не происходит, управление переходит в конструктор потока, а так как там нечего нет, возвращается в поток формы. 
Даже **Resume()** не помогает.

```
thr->Resume();
```

С помощью **Breakpoint** было выяснено что управление методу **Execute()** передается только тогда, когда завершается код потока формы.

**Вот мой код возможно, что я чего-то не понял и не так написал:**

**Unit1.h**
*

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#ifndef Unit1H
#define Unit1H
#include "Unit2.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <Classes.hpp>
#include <Controls.hpp>
#include <StdCtrls.hpp>
#include <Forms.hpp>
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
class TForm1 : public TForm
{
__published:    // IDE-managed Components
        TEdit *Edit1;
        TEdit *Edit2;
private:    // User declarations
public:     // User declarations
        ThreadUDPServer *thr;
        __fastcall TForm1(TComponent* Owner);
};
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
extern PACKAGE TForm1 *Form1;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#endif
```

*
**Unit1.cpp**

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop

#include "Unit1.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TForm1 *Form1;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner)
        : TForm(Owner)
{
        thr = new ThreadUDPServer(false);        // создаем поток в приостановленном состоянии (true), запущенном (false)
        //thr->Resume();  // запустить поток выполняться

        Edit1->Text = thr->buf[0];
        Edit2->Text = thr->buf[1];
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Unit2.h**

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#ifndef Unit2H
#define Unit2H
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <Classes.hpp>
#include "winsock2.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
class ThreadUDPServer : public TThread
{            
private:
protected:
        void __fastcall Execute();
public:
        char buf[20];

        __fastcall ThreadUDPServer(bool CreateSuspended);
};
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#endif
```

**Unit2.cpp**

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop

#include "Unit1.h"
#include "Unit2.h"
#pragma package(smart_init)
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

//   Important: Methods and properties of objects in VCL can only be
//   used in a method called using Synchronize, for example:
//
//      Synchronize(UpdateCaption);
//
//   where UpdateCaption could look like:
//
//      void __fastcall ThreadUDPServer::UpdateCaption()
//      {
//        Form1->Caption = "Updated in a thread";
//      }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

__fastcall ThreadUDPServer::ThreadUDPServer(bool CreateSuspended)
        : TThread(CreateSuspended)
{
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

void __fastcall ThreadUDPServer::Execute()
{
        FreeOnTerminate = true; // освободить занятую потоком память по окончании его работы

        const int iReqWinsockVer = 2;
        WSADATA wsaData;

        if (WSAStartup(iReqWinsockVer,&wsaData)==0)
        {
                ShowMessage("Инициализация библиотеки сокета(Ws2_32.dll) удалась");
                SOCKET s;
                s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);

                if (s == INVALID_SOCKET)
                        ShowMessage("При создании сокета возникла ошибка: " + WSAGetLastError());
                else
                        ShowMessage("Создание сокета было успешным!");

                sockaddr_in sockAddr;
                sockAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
                sockAddr.sin_port = htons(80);
                sockAddr.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = INADDR_ANY;

                if (bind(s, (sockaddr*)(&sockAddr), sizeof(sockAddr))!=0)
                        ShowMessage("Связывание адреса с socket’ом не произошло");
                else
                        ShowMessage("Связывание адреса с socket’ом было успешным!");


                buf[0] = '1';

                ShowMessage(buf[0]);

                while(true)
                {
                        sockaddr_in client_addr;
                        int iSize = sizeof(client_addr);

                        int ret = recvfrom(s, buf, sizeof(buf), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr, &iSize);

                        if (ret != 0)
                        {
                                ShowMessage("Данные были полученны успешно!");
                                ShowMessage(buf[0]);
                                ShowMessage(buf[1]);
                                break;
                        }
                        else
                                ShowMessage("При получении данных возникла ошибка");
                }
                closesocket(s);

                if (WSACleanup() == 0)
                        ShowMessage("Освобождение ресурсов WinSock завершилось успехом");
                else
                        ShowMessage("Освобождение ресурсов WinSock не удалось");
        }
        else
                ShowMessage("Инициализация библиотеки сокета(Ws2_32.dll) не удалась");
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 2):

Я бы не стал образовывать поток в конструкторе формы или в OnFormCreate. Попробуйте с кнопки. Хотя, быть может я и не прав. Но я всегда запускал поток с уже окончательно созданной формы.

Comment: Да, скорее всего, вы правы. Но как организовать всё так, что-бы поток получал данные через сокеты, а форма в это время выводила результат в Edit1 и Edit2. Вот в этом у меня не понимание, как все это сделать?

Comment: Вставьте соответствующий #include "Form1.h" в файл потока. И в Execute() всё и производите. Файл потока будет знать про ваши Edit-ы